# In what scenario would viewProviders be useful in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, dependency-injection, angular5

This is what dependency injection tree looks like when you use viewProvider.

[image: dependency]

As per my understanding: 
If I have `SimpleService` in providers in ngModule and at the same time `SimpleService` in `viewProviders` in `ParentComponent` :

When a child component view(which has been injected via `ng-content`) requests a dependency, it goes directly to the `ngModules`'s providers instead of parents.

Therefore, all Parent components (and their views that were not injected by `ng-content`) would have a separate new instance of the `SimpleService` for themselves but the views which were injected via `ng-content` will have singleton instance shared among them which is the one provided by `NgModule`.

For all Components(Parent Component) that have `SimpleService` in their `viewProviders`, they and their Views(not inject via ng-content) will each have a separate instance of the SimpleService.

```
ParentComponent1-->SimpleServiceInstance1
ParentComponent1's View-->SimpleServiceInstance1

ParentComponent2-->SimpleServiceInstance2
ParentComponent2's View-->SimpleServiceInstance2

ParentComponent3-->SimpleServiceInstance3
ParentComponent3's View(injected via ng-content) -->SimpleServiceInstanceFromNgModuleWhichIsSingleton

ParentComponent4-->SimpleServiceInstance4
ParentComponent4's View(injected via ng-content) -->SimpleServiceInstanceFromNgModuleWhichIsSingleton
```

Is my understanding correct? If yes then in what real world scenario would you use viewProvider? I need an actual example.